# Backspace mapping not working

Tags: neovim, init.lua

Can tell me someone why in nvim backspace don't get triggered in insert mode when setting this keymap:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("i", "<bs>", "<bs><c-g>u", { noremap = true, silent = true } )
```

Trying to do this:
https://github.com/neovim/neovim/discussions/27161

*NVIM v0.9.4*

Mappings:

```
" with autopair
:verbose imap <BS>
i <BS>  *@v:lua.MPairs.autopairs_bs()
  Last set from Lua
i <BS>  * x
  Last set from Lua
:verbose imap <Enter>
i <CR>  * <Lua 308: ~/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-cmp/lua/cmp/utils/keymap.lua:127>
          cmp.utils.set_map
  Last set from Lua

" without autopair
:verbose imap <BS>
i <BS>  * x
  Last set from Lua
[<enter> unchanged]
```

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) It seems to work fine for me (If I hit Backspace Neovim start a new undo block). Maybe you could describe more precisely the symptom. What do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: Hey :) @VivianDeSmedt
Okay, that's great to hear... 
Well, nothing happens when i press only the <bs> key. 
It works only in combination with other keys. Just the <bs> key on its own, 
works only in other modes but not in insert mode... It should delete 1 char and set a undo block... 
Also tried it to unmap with <NOP> but doesn't work neither...
Is there a proper way to unmap the <bs> key...?
Found this in the docs: nvim_del_keymap()
But couldn't get this running...  
Docs: https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As said it work for me. To test your mapping you try to remap to `x` to check that the basic is working (`<bs>` should the lead to inserting `x`) Then you could try `<bs>y` (`<bs>` should lead to replacing the last character by `y`). I'm interested by the result of the following command `:verbose imap <bs>` after each mappings.

Comment: I tried what you said... here is the outcome:
Line 1: i <BS>  *@v:lua.MPairs.autopairs_bs()  Last set from Lua
Line 2: i <BS>  * x  Last set from Lua.....
The funny thing is that <bs><bs> works... heres the output:
Line 1: i <BS>  *@v:lua.MPairs.autopairs_bs()  Last set from Lua
Line 2: i <BS><BS>  * <BS><C-G>U  Last set from Lua....
Then i tried enter with inserting x this doesn't work nether... Output:
i  <CR>      * <Lua 316: ~/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-cmp/lua/cmp/utils/keyma
p.lua:127>              cmp.utils.keymap.set_map
       Last set from Lua

Great command by the way :D

Comment: Crazy, thank your help i could identify it... it was the cmp plugin..
Thx a lot , you saved me

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) I'm happy that we could help you ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments it seems to me that the `<BS>` key is remapped at the buffer level by:

- [nvim-autopairs](https://github.com/windwp/nvim-autopairs)
- [nvim-cmp](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp)

To validate my hypothesis I would deactivate these two plugins and verify that your mapping is working fine when they are deactivated.

Use the following command to verify that your mapping is in place:

```
:verbose imap <BS>
```

Or make a more obvious version (like `x` or `<BS>y` to test)

I you insist to have your mapping in the presence of the plugins you'll have to do something complex like:

- Make sure your mapping is at buffer level and is set after the plugins make their mapping (to make sure it is not overridden)
- To not lose the plugin functionality you'll have to add the plugin mapping (probably a `<Plug>` mapping) to your mapping (at the start or at the end what is the most appropriate) to get both.

Answer (score 1):

```
" with autopair
:verbose imap <BS>
i <BS>  *@v:lua.MPairs.autopairs_bs()
  Last set from Lua
i <BS>  * x
  Last set from Lua
:verbose imap <Enter>
i <CR>  * <Lua 308: ~/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-cmp/lua/cmp/utils/keymap.lua:127>
          cmp.utils.set_map
  Last set from Lua

" without autopair
:verbose imap <BS>
i <BS>  * x
  Last set from Lua
[<enter> unchanged]
```

The problem was autopair:
in the above text you can see the mappings on <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> with and without the plugin.

I made a mapping with `<bs>` inserting x and a mapping with `<enter>` inserting x.

Comment: This seems like an edit to the original question rather than an answer. In the meantime, I've edited for clarity and grammar. [Text is usually preferred over images](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)